# ¿La forma correcta de hacer esta petición con postman?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

Estoy realizando una petición con postman `(POST())` en la que envío el usuario y la contraseña, pero me da error y aunque parece que es de sintaxis, no acabo de verlo.

Esta es la función del modelo:

```
public function get_usuario_maestro($username) {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM maestro WHERE username LIKE' . $username . ';');
    }
```

Función del api:

```
public function login_post() {

        $username = $this->post('username');
        $contrasenia = $this->post('contrasenia');

        $usuario = $this->maestro_model->get_usuario_maestro($username);

        if ($usuario == NULL) { //usuario que no existe
            $this->set_response(['status' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Error 404'], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        } elseif (!password_verify($contrasenia, $usuario->$contrasenia)) { //contraseña incorrecta
            $this->set_response(['status' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Error 404'], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        } else { //existe
            $this->set_response(['status' => TRUE, 'message' => 'Login OK', 'idMaestro' => $usuario->idMaestro], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }
    }
```

Error en postman:

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
<p>Error Number: 1054</p>
<p>Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'</p>
<p>SELECT * FROM maestro WHERE username LIKE "";</p>
```

Comment: Seguro que maestro tiene campo username?

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista parece que tienes que poner comillas en la consulta cuando le pasas el USUARIO

```
public function get_usuario_maestro($username) {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM maestro WHERE username LIKE "' . $username . '";');
    }
```

El segundo error te esta dicendo la base de datos que esa columna no existe.
Comprueba las mayúsculas del nombre en la base de datos

______Si no entra dentro de la sentencia IF pueden ser por:

1. No se reciben parametros en la funcion login_post  ->

Haz echo para ver que si se reciven echo   $username .  $contrasenia ;

2. La contraseña en BB.DD esta almacenada con otro HASH ->

En el else if estas usando la funcion http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php Sacalo de la funcion y mira lo que devuelve

3. Estas enviando la contraseña ya encriptada en el formulario ->

Observa el `echo` del punto 1

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, arreglé lo que me dijiste y ahora aparece lo siguiente:

<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
            <p>Error Number: 1054</p>
            <p>Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'</p>
            <p>SELECT * FROM maestro WHERE username LIKE "";</p>

Comment: He colocado el error más arriba, para que sea legible

Comment: cierto, tienes toda la razón, me había cambiado el nombre de la columna de la base de datos, ahora parece que todo anda correcto pero me da el error 404 
{
  "status": false,
  "message": "Error 404"
}

Comment: Me está entrando en la condición 404 de la función y no entiendo por qué, porque hay un usuario creado y con un GET() lo devuelve

Comment: Ya, pero eso es la Salida del condicional IF. Supongo que te refieres a que pasandole el usuario y la password correcto, entra en una parte de la sentencia IF que no deberia...es correcto lo que digo?

Comment: Correcto, entra donde no debería

Comment: ocurre esto sacándolo de la función:

{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Login OK",
  "idMaestro": null
}

Comment: entonces todo ok?

Comment: Y haciendo lo del echo que me dijiste sale (da usuario y contraseña):

{
  "status": false,
  "myEcho": "palma1"
}

Lo que me extraña es que el id lo esté pillando a NULL

Comment: espera no habrás QUITADO` password_verify` de la sentencia` IF` ???

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56129/discussion-between-jose-and-carlos-g-munoz).

Answer (score 0):

Dice que el campo 'username' no existe en la tabla 'maestro', tal vez sea 'user_name' o algo parecido, revisa directamente en la db el nombre del campo. Saludos.